# How do i switch from ubuntu back to chrome OS?

Tags: 13.10

I have 13.10 installed and im stuck on ubuntu and have it as my default load up as ubuntu. Whats the commands to get back? I have tried everything i seen on other websites but im still haveing some trouble so please help me. Im on a acer 710 chrome book.

Answer (score 0):

When booting press tab to enter to the GRUB menu and there you can enter back to your chrome OS.

Or edit /etc/default/grub

change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value to -1

This will ensure that you enter GRUB always to choose which os you want to boot 
then do the command

```
sudo apt-get update-grub
```